# Cannot Redeclare Function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, bubble-sort

I have created a WordPress plugin that will sort social media profiles and output them by the order number. I have an issue that if I have the plugin on the page more than 1 time, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare bh_sort_profiles() (previously declared in 
/Users/brturpin/Sites/plugin-development/wp-content/plugins/bh-social- 
icons/inc/output.php:68) in /Users/brturpin/Sites/plugin-development/ 
wp-content/plugins/bh-social-icons/inc/output.php on line 78
```

I understand that is is cause the function I use to sort the profiles is being called twice now, but not sure how to do it so I do not have this error:

CODE:

```
$bh_social_profile_array = array (
array(
    "id" => "facebook",
    "url" => $facebook_url,
    "class" => "icon-facebook",
    "color" => $facebook_color,
    "order" => $facebook_order
    ),
array(
    "id" => "twitter",
    "url" => $twitter_url,
    "class" => "icon-twitter-1",
    "color" => $twitter_color,
    "order" => $twitter_order
    ),
array(
    "id" => "pinterest",
    "url" => $pinterest_url,
    "class" => "icon-pinterest",
    "color" => $pinterest_color,
    "order" => $pinterest_order
    ),
array(
    "id" => "instagram",
    "url" => $instagram_url,
    "class" => "icon-instagram",
    "color" => $instagram_color,
    "order" => $instagram_order
    ),
array(
    "id" => "gplus",
    "url" => $gplus_url,
    "class" => "icon-gplus",
    "color" => $gplus_color,
    "order" => $gplus_order,
    ),
array(
    "id" => "linkedin",
    "url" => $linkedin_url,
    "class" => "icon-linkedin",
    "color" => $linkedin_color,
    "order" => $linkedin_order
    ),
array(
    "id" => "youtube",
    "url" => $youtube_url,
    "class" => "icon-youtube",
    "color" => $youtube_color,
    "order" => $youtube_order
    ),
array(
    "id" => "rss",
    "url" => $rss_url,
    "class" => "icon-rss",
    "color" => $rss_color,
    "order" => $rss_order
    ),
);


function bh_sort_profiles($arr) {
    $size = count($arr);
    for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j<$size-1-$i; $j++) {
            if ($arr[$j+1]["order"] < $arr[$j]["order"]) {
                swap($arr, $j, $j+1);
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

function swap(&$arr, $a, $b) {
    $tmp = $arr[$a];
    $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
    $arr[$b] = $tmp;
}

$bh_sorted_profiles = bh_sort_profiles($bh_social_profile_array);

?>

<div style="text-align: <?php echo $social_align; ?>;">
    <?php foreach($bh_sorted_profiles as $i => $profile): ?>

        <?php if ($profile["url"] != ""): ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $profile["url"]; ?>" class="social-icons <?php echo $profile["class"]; ?>" style="background-color: <?php if ($profile['color'] != '') { echo $profile['color']; } ?>; color: <?php echo $text_color; ?>; font-size: <?php echo $font_size; ?>; border-radius: <?php echo $border_radius; ?>" target="<?php echo $new_window; ?>"></a>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Declare your functions in a different file and include it with `include_once()`.